# Transforming from char * to char[]

Tags: c, char

I am getting segmentation fault in the following code

```
static char * result;

char s[31];

int i;

random_string(s, 10);



 // for (i = 0; i < 15; i++){
 //     result[i] = s[i];
 // }

strcpy(result, s);

printf("el result es %s\n", result);
```

where the function random_string is:

```
void random_string(char * string, int length)
 {
  /* Seed number for rand() */

 int i;

for (i = 0; i < length -1; ++i){

    string[i] = rand() % 90 + 65;
 }

 string[length] = '\0';
}
```

For some reason I am getting segmentation fault when using strcpy. Also copying byte by byte is not working. What is the problem? I am out of ideas.

Comment: You should allocate the memory for the array... Look up malloc...

Comment: This very same beginner bug question has been asked 2 times earlier this hour only. Kindly put some minimum effort into researching before posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static char * result; is just an address without any allocated memory!

Try this:
[EDITED]

```
char * result = (char*)malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
```

Comment: yeah that was it. Thanks. And yeah I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me :)

Comment: This code snippet is kind of scary, of course you can't call `strlen(s)` before writing to `s`. I assume that the OP's code is implied to go between the two lines, somehow.

Comment: Please do NOT cast malloc return value - it can hide certain subtle errors.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `result` has not been initialized.  It results in undefined behavior. Before it can be used like that, you need to make sure it points to a valid buffer.  For example:

```
result = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to allocate memory to "result" pointer. Try next:

```
result = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 );
strcpy(result, s);
```

Comment: Please [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) in C.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have deep knowledge of C.

Answer (score 0):

result is just a uninitialised pointer.
You must assign result to a character buffer before using strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a valid memory region to your result pointer using malloc or using static memory, as you are doing with your s string. Otherwise your pointer has just a random location assigned and your program receives a segfault by accessing it as it lies out of the boundaries of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Declare result as a char array like 
static char result[10];

or assign some memory to result pointer.